# Creating a sparse matrix in CHOLMOD or SuiteSparseQR

Tags: c++, libraries, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, suitesparse

In [SparseSuiteQR](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/SPQR/), all of the examples I can find use stdin or a file read to create a sparse matrix. Could someone provide a simple example of how to create one directly in C++?

Even better, in the CHOLMOD documentation, there is mention of a sparse2 function available in matlab, which behaves the same as the sparse. Can this be used in C++?

Answer (score 2):

The data structures used by SuiteSparseQR (e.g. cholmod_sparse) are defined in the CHOLMOD library. You can find more information about it on the CHOLMOD documentation, which is much larger than the one from SuiteSparseQR.

Comment: `CHOLMOD documentation` **and source code**

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you try to solve a linear system, see the CSparse package from Tim Davies, or boost matrix libraries which also have numeric bindings which interface umfpack and some lapack functions AFAIK...

Comment: Yes, I will be solving a linear system. I'm using boost ublas, and I saw the bindings for umfpack which looks easy to use, but the documentation says it is for unsymmetric matrices, and I have a symmetric. Looking closer though it looks like it can handle symmetric so I will give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CHOLMOD is a pretty awesome project - thanks Tim Davis :)

There is surprisingly a lot of code on GitHub that makes use of CHOLMOD, *but* you have to be logged into GitHub and know what you're looking for!

So, after crawling through CHOLMOD documentation and source code and then searching through GitHub for *source code* that uses CHOLMOD you would find out what to do.

But for most developers who want/need a quick example, here it is below.

*Note that your mileage might vary depending on how you compiled SuiteSparse.
(You might need to use the `cholmod_` variant (without the `l`), i.e. not `cholmod_l_`; and use `int` for indexing, not `long int`).

```
// example.cpp
#include "SuiteSparseQR.hpp"
#include "SuiteSparse_config.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  cholmod_common Common, *cc;
  cholmod_sparse *A;
  cholmod_dense *X, *B;

  // start CHOLMOD
  cc = &Common;
  cholmod_l_start (cc);

  /* A =
      [
        1.1,  0.0, -0.5,  0.7
        0.0, -2.0,  0.0,  0.0
        0.0,  0.0,  0.9,  0.0
        0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.6
      ]
  */
  int m = 4;   // num rows in A
  int n = 4;   // num cols in A
  int nnz = 6; // num non-zero elements in A
  int unsymmetric = 0; // A is non-symmetric: see cholmod.h > search for `stype` for more details

  // In coordinate form (COO) a.k.a. triplet form (zero-based indexing)
  int i[nnz] = {0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3}; // row indices
  int j[nnz] = {0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}; // col indices
  double x[nnz] = {1.1, -2.0, -0.5, 0.9, 0.7, 0.6}; // values

  // Set up the cholmod matrix in COO/triplet form
  cholmod_triplet *T = cholmod_l_allocate_triplet(m, n, nnz, unsymmetric, CHOLMOD_REAL, cc);
  T->nnz = nnz;

  for (int ind = 0; ind < nnz; ind++)
  {
    ((long int *) T->i)[ind] = i[ind];     // Notes:
    ((long int *) T->j)[ind] = j[ind];     // (1) casting necessary because these are void* (see cholmod.h)
    ((double *) T->x)[ind] = x[ind];       // (2) direct assignment will cause memory corruption
  }                                        // (3) long int for index pointers corresponds to usage of cholmod_l_* functions

  // convert COO/triplet to CSC (compressed sparse column) format
  A = (cholmod_sparse *) cholmod_l_triplet_to_sparse(T, nnz, cc);
  // note: if you already know CSC format you can skip the triplet allocation and instead use cholmod_allocate_sparse
  //       and assign the member variables: see cholmod.h > cholmod_sparse_struct definition

  // B = ones (size (A,1),1)
  B = cholmod_l_ones (A->nrow, 1, A->xtype, cc);

  // X = A\B
  X = SuiteSparseQR <double> (A, B, cc);

  // Print contents of X
  printf("X = [\n");
  for (int ind = 0; ind < n; ind++)
  {
    printf("%f\n", ((double *) X->x)[ind]);
  }
  printf("]\n");
  fflush(stdout);

  // free everything and finish CHOLMOD
  cholmod_l_free_triplet (&T, cc);
  cholmod_l_free_sparse (&A, cc);
  cholmod_l_free_dense (&X, cc);
  cholmod_l_free_dense (&B, cc);
  cholmod_l_finish (cc);
  return 0;
}
```

Supposing you have compiled SuiteSparse successfully and you have saved `example.cpp` in the base directory, then the following should work (on Linux):

```
gcc example.cpp -I./include -L./lib -lcholmod -lspqr -lsuitesparseconfig -o example
#Add SuiteSpare libraries to your `ld` search path if necessary
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd)/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./example
```

Output:

```
X = [
0.353535
-0.500000
1.111111
1.666667
]
```